# Unable to create database by cake bake db_config

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mamp

I'm creating `database.php` file by `cake bake db_config`

```
Database Configuration:
---------------------------------------------------------------
Name:
[default] >
Datasource: (Mysql/Postgres/Sqlite/Sqlserver)
[Mysql] >
Persistent Connection? (y/n)
[n] >
Database Host:
[localhost] >
Port?
[n] >
User:
[root] >
Password:
>
Database Name:
[cake] > testdb
Table Prefix?
[n] >
Table encoding?
[n] >

---------------------------------------------------------------
The following database configuration will be created:
---------------------------------------------------------------
Name:         default
Datasource:   Mysql
Persistent:   false
Host:         localhost
User:         root
Pass:         ****
Database:     testdb
---------------------------------------------------------------
Look okay? (y/n)
[y] > y
Do you wish to add another database configuration?
[n] >

Wrote `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/linda/app/Config/database.php`
```

It does create the `database.php` file, but when I test it in a browser, I'm getting this message

```
Cake is NOT able to connect to the database.
Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created.
```

Only, when I create database manually by `phpMyAdmin` it starts working fine.

What should I fix/do to be able to create database by `cake bake db_config`

Using `MAMP` and `CakePHP 2.4.0`

Doesn't get any errors when trying to create `database.php`, also have no errors in log files:

```
apache_error.log    
mysql_error_log.err 
php_error.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cake bake doesn't create the database for you, you need to create it manually before you create the database configuration file.